# Memory leak: steady increase in memory usage with simple device motion logging

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, memory-management, memory-leaks

Consider this simple Swift code that logs device motion data to a CSV file on disk.

```
let motionManager = CMMotionManager() 
var handle: NSFileHandle? = nil

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let documents = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
    let file = documents.stringByAppendingPathComponent("/data.csv")

    NSFileManager.defaultManager().createFileAtPath(file, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
    handle = NSFileHandle(forUpdatingAtPath: file)

    motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue(), withHandler: {(data, error) in
        let data_points = [data.timestamp, data.attitude.roll, data.attitude.pitch, data.attitude.yaw, data.userAcceleration.x,
            data.userAcceleration.y, data.userAcceleration.z, data.rotationRate.x, data.rotationRate.y, data.rotationRate.z]

        let line = ",".join(data_points.map { $0.description }) + "\n"
        let encoded = line.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

        self.handle!.writeData(encoded)
    })
}
```

I've been stuck on this for days. There appears to be a memory leak, as memory 
consumption steadily increases until the OS suspends the app for exceeding resources.

[image: Memory usage]

It's critical that this app be able to run for long periods without interruption. Some notes:

- I've tried using NSOutputStream and a CSV-writing library (CHCSVParser), but the issue is still present
- Executing the logging code asynchronously (wrapping `startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue` in `dispatch_async`) does not remove the issue
- Performing the sensor data processing in a background `NSOperationQueue` *does* fix the issue (only when `maxConcurrentOperationCount` >= 2). However, that causes concurrency issues in file writing: the output file is garbled with lines intertwined between each other.
- The issue does not seem to appear when logging accelerometer data only, but does seem to appear when logging multiple sensors (e.g. accelerometer + gyroscope). Perhaps there's a threshold of file writing throughput that triggers this issue?
- The memory spikes seem to be spaced out at roughly 10 second intervals (steps in the above graph). Perhaps that's indicative of something? (could be an artifact of the memory instrumentation infrastructure, or perhaps it's garbage collection)

Any pointers? I've tried to use Instruments, but I don't have the skills the use it effectively. It seems that the exploding memory usage is caused by `__NSOperationInternal`. Here's a sample [Instruments trace](http://static.davidchouinard.com/StackOverflow-memorytest.zip).

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have anything else going on elsewhere?  I ran your provided code, and don't get anywhere near the stair step in memory usage you are seeing.  On a side note, logging all of the events will grow the CSV file fairly quickly.

Comment: @JeremyPope ugh. I have a brand new development-only iPhone 6; restarted it and made sure no apps where suspended/in the background. I started a new XCode project, didn't touch anything and added my code. Issue still present. ([sample XCode project](http://static.davidchouinard.com/StackOverflow-MemoryLeak.zip))

Comment: Stair step I get with that XCode project: http://imgur.com/p6cYAGu

Comment: Weird, I rebuilt it a few time and now I see it as well.

Comment: To me, the code looks perfectly cromulent.  NSOutputStream might be a better option than NSFileHandle for writing, but NSFileHandle should work fine.  I don't see anything else that could leak.  Perhaps rewriting in Objective-C just to see what happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, see this answer of mine:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28566113/341994

You should not be looking at the Memory graphs in the debugger; believe only what Instruments tells you. Debug builds and Release builds are memory-managed very differently in Swift.

Second, if there is still trouble, try wrapping the interior of your handler in an `autoreleasepool` closure. I do not expect that that would make a difference, however (as this is not a loop), and I do not expect that it will be necessary, as I suspect that using Instruments will reveal that there was never any problem in the first place. However, the `autoreleasepool` call will make sure that autoreleased objects are not given a chance to accumulate.

Comment: Wow. This is it. I wish I could get back the week of my life I wasted on this — I feel Apple should at least have a disclaimer warning in the XCode tools.

Thank you. I don't think I would have ever discovered this.

Comment: "In a room with an unlocked door that opens inwards, a man will be a prisoner until it occurs to him to pull rather than push." - Wittgenstein

Comment: @David, what was it?  When I profile it in Instruments, the memory still continues to climb continuously, granted not as bad as in the debugger, but it still continues to climb endlessly.  Did you add an autoreleasepool?  I did find a way around the never ending memory allocations, but it didn't involve an autoreleasepool.

Comment: @JeremyPope: I didn't test on the toy sample I provided, but I made a release build of my code and used Instruments to profile. I didn't attempt to use Instruments on a debug build (as suggested by @matt) — that might be it.

Comment: Yeah, I was doing release builds in instruments, but the memory kept climbing.  Ultimately I had to refactor the join / map routine for creating the lines, to make the memory behave.