# memory detector of xcode seems weird

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, afnetworking, xcode7, instruments

I'm using `AFNetworking` for downloading video file from server. Since my app target on `iOS7+`, i use method `downloadTaskWithRequest:progress:destination:completionHandler:`

When i download a large file(400M), the memory detector of xcode seems weird, the memory keeps growing and several `Received Memory Warning` print in the console, then my app is killed.

[image: memory detector of xcode]

But when i profile with `Instruments`, the allocations of memory seem to be stable.

[image]

The app does not crash if i run my app directly without debug, crash only appears when running with xcode.
Is this a bug of xcode? or my app has memory issues(may be memory leaks)??

**Update:**
Xcode version 7.1.1, iOS8.3, Using Objective-C

Comment: Turn off NSZombie detection.

Comment: @Avi Enable Zombie Objects option in the `Diagnostics` isn't selected.

Comment: someone has the same problem, got one answer, but still confused(if the memory monitor of xcode is not correct, why should it be used in xcode). Run in release mode, still have the problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28321954/ios-memory-usage-increasing-cant-find-the-culprit?rq=1

Comment: Huh.  That fixed it for me.  In any event, if you care about memory usage, use Instruments.  (edit) Have you tried an Analyze run, to see if it finds any memory leaks?

Comment: I'd advise turning off `Enable backtrace recording` as well, except for when you need it. That eats a lot of memory