# Does Xcode's Debug Navigator work different from Instruments allocations?

Tags: xcode, memory-management, memory-leaks, allocation, xcode-instruments

I'm trying to find memory issues in my app.

When I use Xcode's debug navigator for memory issues I see increase in the overall usage of the application. For a specific flow, when I go back and forth I don't see memory being persisted.

However if I go through same flow and instrument using Allocations, I do see 3Mbs getting persisted every time I go back and forth.

Is Xcode's debug navigator not reliable or they're measuring something different or something else?!

**EDIT:**

So I've been told the difference is due to the build configuration. OK. But if I go and 'edit scheme' and change the build configuration to 'release' and run on my device. Can I then expect the Xcode debug navigator to work the same? Or still there are some differences? If so what?

Comment: What build configurations are you using in the debugger and Instruments? Xcode defaults to running debug builds in the debugger and release builds in Instruments. Debug and release builds can cause different amounts of memory usage.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to take a look and get back to you. But that might just be it. For now can you just add an answer instead and add references for what you just said?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is Xcode's debug navigator not reliable or they're measuring something different

Absolutely yes! As I have advised here many times ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28566113/341994) for example), you must *never* draw real conclusions from the debug navigator gauges. Memory allocation works completely differently in a debug build in the simulator. If you want to know how your app's memory works, you must use Instruments so that you get a release build, and you must run on a device so that your memory usage reflects real-world conditions.

> But if I go and 'edit scheme' and change the build configuration to 'release'  ... Can I then expect the Xcode debug navigator to work the same

Absolutely no! Release means all sorts of compiler optimizations are performed that make the debugger almost impossible to use. But that doesn't matter; you would never debug *and* use Instruments to measure anything at the same time.

Comment: I made a small edit to my question. Can you take a look again?

Comment: Yep, did so, no problem.

Comment: Thanks. So Release + debugger can never happen. While debug and instruments don't happen _unless_ I go and change the build configuration of Profile. But that would be a weird thing to do. Was that a correct summary?

Comment: Basically the correct summary is that if you debug when you debug and profile when you profile, the right thing happens automatically, because it's been configured correctly by Apple at the factory. :)

Comment: @matt Regarding OP's 2nd question, of course release builds make the _debugger_ harder to use because of optimizations, but what bearing does that have on the question of whether the memory graph in XCode when running a release build will match the same release build being profiled in Instruments? Shouldn't we at least in this case expect consistent results in terms of total memory alive at a given time?

Comment: @Danny all I can tell you is my experience which is that results in the memory graph sometimes differ from results in Instruments, so I trust instruments.

Comment: @matt Fair enough - after some further research I'm realizing the whole story is a lot more complex in that the default view in Instruments may not capture certain types of VM memory, dirty memory, etc. And the "Activity Monitor" instrument does appear to show consistent memory usage compared with XCode's memory graph. FWIW

Answer (score 6):

Xcode's default behavior is to use a debug build when running your project in Xcode and to use a release build when profiling the project in Instruments. Debug and release builds can have different amounts of memory usage.

You can check and change the build configuration from Xcode's scheme editor.

[image]

If that doesn't solve your issue, you're going to have a tough time getting a definitive answer. The people who know the inner workings and the differences between the debugger and Instruments are Apple engineers.

Comment: Do you mean when I click on profile, because it's normally set to **release** mode then it's considered a release build? That makes sense

Comment: Yes, if the Profile step is set to use the Release build configuration, it's considered a release build.

Comment: I made a small edit to my question. Can you take a look again?

Comment: Matt beat me to the answer. I don't have anything else to add.

Comment: That's fine. Just that your comment/answer came first...so bounty goes to you. Accepted answer goes to him :D. I have other questions you can answer :))) Including one other with a bounty