# Memory usage keeps rising on older devices using Metal

Tags: ios, swift, metal, core-image, cadisplaylink

I use `Metal` and `CADisplayLink` to live filter a `CIImage` and render it into a `MTKView`.

```
// Starting display link 
displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(applyAnimatedFilter))
displayLink.preferredFramesPerSecond = 30
displayLink.add(to: .current, forMode: .default)

@objc func applyAnimatedFilter() {
    ...
    metalView.image = filter.applyFilter(image: ciImage)
}
```

According to the memory monitor in Xcode, memory usage is stable on iPhone X and never goes above 100mb, on devices like iPhone 6 or iPhone 6s the memory usage keeps growing until eventually the system kills the app.

I've checked for memory leaks using `Instruments`, but no leaks were reported. Running the app through Allocations also don't show any problems and the app won't get shut down by the system. I also find it interesting that on newer devices the memory usage is stable but on older it just keeps growing and growing.

The filter's complexity don't matter as I tried even most simple filters and the issue persists. Here is an example from my metal file:

```
extern "C" { namespace coreimage {

    float4 applyColorFilter(sample_t s, float red, float green, float blue) {

        float4 newPixel = s.rgba;
        newPixel[0] = newPixel[0] + red;
        newPixel[1] = newPixel[1] + green;
        newPixel[2] = newPixel[2] + blue;

        return newPixel;
    }
}
```

I wonder what can cause the issue on older devices and in which direction I should look up to.

**Update 1:** here are two 1 minute graphs, one from `Xcode` and one from `Allocations` both using the same filter. `Allocations` graph is stable while `Xcode` graph is always growing:

[image: Xcode]

[image: Allocations]

**Update 2:** Attaching a screenshot of Allocations List sorted by size, the app was running for 16 minutes, applying the filter non stop:

[image]

**Update 3:** A bit more info on what is happening in `applyAnimatedFilter()`:

I render a filtered image into a `metalView` which is a `MTKView`. I receive the filtered image from `filter.applyFilter(image: ciImage)`, where in `Filter` class happens next:

```
 func applyFilter(image: ciImage) -> CIImage {
    ...
    var colorMix = ColorMix()
    return colorMix.use(image: ciImage, time: filterTime)
 }
```

where `filterTime` is just a Double variable. And finally, here is the whole ColorMix class:

```
import UIKit

class ColorMix: CIFilter {

    private let kernel: CIKernel

    @objc dynamic var inputImage: CIImage?
    @objc dynamic var inputTime: CGFloat = 0

    override init() {

        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "default", withExtension: "metallib")!
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
        kernel = try! CIKernel(functionName: "colorMix", fromMetalLibraryData: data)
        super.init()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func outputImage() -> CIImage? {

        guard let inputImage = inputImage else {return nil}

        return kernel.apply(extent: inputImage.extent, roiCallback: {
            (index, rect) in
            return rect.insetBy(dx: -1, dy: -1)
        }, arguments: [inputImage, CIVector(x: inputImage.extent.width, y: inputImage.extent.height), inputTime])
    }

    func use(image: CIImage, time: Double) -> CIImage {

        var resultImage = image

        // 1. Apply filter
        let filter = ColorMix()
        filter.setValue(resultImage, forKey: "inputImage")
        filter.setValue(NSNumber(floatLiteral: time), forKey: "inputTime")

        resultImage = filter.outputImage()!

        return resultImage
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try adding an autorelease pool?

Comment: @matt I didn't, I thought it doesn't do much in a Swift only project?

Comment: Well, you thought wrong about that. :) I'm not promising it will solve this particular problem, but at least let's try it. Wrap the whole interior of `applyAnimatedFilter` in an `autoreleasepool` block and let's see if makes any difference.

Comment: @matt thanks, I will try it right now :) Also I've noticed that when running the app on Allocations through Instruments, it won't get killed and the memory graph is stable. Could there be any differences in memory management between Xcode and Instruments?

Comment: @matt Adding `autireleasepool` didn't make a difference according to Xcode memory graph

Comment: OK but hold it. It sounds to me like you might be making the mistake I describe here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52634826/341994 If you want to know what your real memory usage is, do a Release build. Instruments does that automatically but if you just build-and-run onto a device you're getting a Debug build, which is different and cannot give you a true picture of memory usage.

Comment: I'm going to guess that this effect is illusory, caused by the fact that you are testing by doing a build-and-run onto your device from Xcode. That's a Debug build. Memory management in a Debug build is not a measure of how your memory will behave in the real app. Instead, create a Scheme whose Run action specifies a Release build and build-and-run from that Scheme. If the memory growth goes away, the problem is solved. (Again, I promise nothing, but hey, it's worth a try.)

Comment: @matt sorry, I got a bit confused :D I just created a new scheme with `Release` build configuration and did a "build and run" on device - the Xcode memory graph still showed a constantly growing memory usage. But when I run it in Instruments, the memory usage seem to be OK. Whom do I trust? :D

Comment: Well, not me, clearly. :( Hmm, you say "the memory usage seem to be OK". But Instruments doesn't show virtual memory, such as images. If you were constantly loading images, I would expect memory to grow but I would not expect Instruments to show that. Is that the case?

Comment: I don't constantly load any images, just processing one single input `CIImage` with Metal filter (which also doesn't involve any images loading, just modifies the input image) and rendering it back to `MTKView`.

Comment: It is likely that the issue is cause by CoreImage allocating and then not effectively releasing backing bitmap buffers when you call applyFilter. I ran into an issue like this with CoreImage invoked from SpriteKit and there appears to be no solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54431826/skeffectnode-combined-with-cifilter-runs-out-of-memory

Comment: @MoDJ It's good that you came along! So did you file an Apple bug report on this?

Comment: @matt I included screenshots of both graphs in the update

Comment: @MoDJ that's a bummer, I wonder why it happens only on older devices though?

Comment: Yes, I filed an bug with Apple. No response after like 6 months. Basically, I decided not to use CoreImage. I am just directly interfacing with the GPU using Metal as this approach does not have memory leaks and you can manage large buffers properly.

Comment: @SmartTree Can you post a screenshot of the Allocations List in Instruments, probably sorted by size? Would be interesting to see what those allocations are.

Comment: Also maybe a bit more detail on what happens inside `applyAnimatedFilter`.

Comment: hey @FrankSchlegel, I updated my answer :)

Comment: Try turning off Metal validation, GPU capture, and maybe other diagnostic options in the scheme. I believe I've seen reports of those causing memory growth like you're describing.

Comment: What is your image size?

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 input UIImage size is: (375.0, 500.0) before I convert it to CIImage

Comment: @SmartTree Could you please also show how you render the `CIImage` into the `MTKView` (what happens when you assign `metalView.image`)?

Comment: @KenThomases cheers, that totally worked! After I disabled those diagnostics in the scheme, the memory graph became stable and the app worked without any problems. Could you make an answer out of that so I accept it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug in Xcode's diagnostic features (Metal validation and/or GPU frame capture). If you turn those off, the memory usage should be similar to when running outside of Xcode.

Comment: This did the trick for me too! I have a video game engine where I've allocated all of the game's memory up front, and it was surprising to me that the memory could possibly keep increasing like that. Thanks!

Comment: SDL was causing a memory leak and low-and-behold it wasn't really SDL, but instead the fact that I had Metal API validation turned on in the Scheme editor. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few observations, but I'm not sure if one of them actually causes the memory usage you're seeing:

- In `applyFilter` you are creating a new `ColorMix` filter *every frame*. Additionally, inside the instance method `use(image:, time:)` you are creating *another one* on every call. That's a lot of overhead, especially since the filter loads it's kernel every time on `init`. It would be advisable to just create a single `ColorMix` filter during setup and just update its `inputImage` and `inputTime` on every frame.
- `outputImage` is not a `func`, but a `var` that you override from the `CIFilter` super class:

  `override var outputImage: CIImage? { /* your code here */ }`
- Is your `colorMix` kernel performing any kind of convolution? If not, it could be a `CIColorKernel` instead.
- If you need the size of the input inside your kernel, you don't need to pass it as extra argument. You can just call `.size()` on the input `sampler`.

Comment: Hey Frank, thanks for your great optimisation tips! I will adapt them in my code. Creating a new filter every frame was really irrational. Ken Thomases suggestion about turning off Metal validation and GPU capture in the scheme did the trick for me and now the memory graph is stable in Xcode.

Comment: Nice! Glad I could help. 