# Does metal drawable cause the memory leak issue?

Tags: metal

According to [this article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/presentation_objects/obtaining_presenting_and_releasing_drawables?language=objc), I embed my render loop within an autorelease pool block. But I found there is still a memory issue with XCode instruments as shown below.
[image: drawable memory leak]

Why are there still memory leaks when embedded within the autorelease pool block? And how to fix it?

**EDIT**
Not memory leak in iOS, but mac has.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56854929/memory-usage-keeps-rising-on-older-devices-using-metal#answer-56872577

Comment: @KenThomases I have disabled both GPU Frame Capture and Metal API Validation, there is still a memory leak on mac when profiling the project in Instruments.